# Why can't my program see function definitions even though the linker finds the object file?

Tags: c++, linker, g++

I have a library (giftiio) with header files in `/usr/include/gifti`, and `libgiftiio.a` in `/usr/lib`.

I try to use it with a simple program, `read_hemi.cc`:

```
#include <gifti_io.h>

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  gifti_image *out_im;
  gifti_disp_lib_version();
}
```

I then try to compile this program with:

```
g++ -lgiftiio -I/usr/include/gifti -I/usr/include/nifti read_hemi.cc
```

and get the following error:

```
/tmp/ccqWBaLb.o: In function `main': 
read_hemi.cc:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `gifti_disp_lib_version()'
```

Note that everything defined in the header file is accessible (such as the gifti_image typedef). But even though the linker doesn't complain at my `-lgiftiio` flag, suggesting it finds the object file, I don't get my function definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> get the following error

Your link command line is wrong, and should be:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/gifti -I/usr/include/nifti read_hemi.cc -lgiftiio
```

To understand why, read [this](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2013/07/09/library-order-in-static-linking/) or [this](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).

**Update:**

> changing the order does not help

From the error message, we see that the unresolved symbol is a C++ mangled one.

Searching for gifti_disp_lib_version, I find this version of [gifti_io.h](https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/pub/dist/freesurfer/tutorial_packages/centos6/fsl_507/include/giftiio/gifti_io.h). It appears that this is a pure-`C` library, and the header lacks proper `C++` guards.

To work around this, you must change your program like so:

```
extern "C" {
#include <gifti_io.h>
}

int main(const int argc, const char *argv[]) {
  // rest as before ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the links, I think I understand them. However, changing the order does not help. If I copy and paste your command I get exactly the same error.

Comment: To be extra safe, I can split the command in two, and compile first:
`g++ -c -I/usr/include/gifti -I/usr/include/nifti read_hemi.cc`
followed by
`g++ read_hemi.o -lgiftiio`
This returns the same error

Comment: @CarsonMcNeil I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a ton! That did the trick. Interesting, I was under the impression that C++ was fully compatible with C...I'll have to read up on this.